# /lib/libc.so.0 error with buildroot

Tags: linux, buildroot

It is seen that sometimes if we select a package we get this strange error from buildroot saying cannot find /lib/libc.so.0 . Further probing it is defined in libc.so found in $(STAGING_DIR)/usr/lib ; if we change the absolute path

GROUP (/lib/libc.so.0 /usr/lib/uclibc_nonshared.a AS_NEEDED (/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0 ) )

to relative path meaning something like below :

GROUP ( ../../lib/libc.so.0 ../usr/lib/uclibc_nonshared.a AS_NEEDED (../../lib/ld-uClibc.so.0 ) )

compilation goes thro' fine. Q? is whether this is the right way to get around this problem ? or we need to do some change so that this file gets generated properly ?; Thanks for any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an External Toolchain? Does it happen with packages that don't use the autotools Makefile?

I think you may need to pass the TARGET_(CFLAGS|LDFLAGS) in the packages .mk files.

something like:

CFLAGS="$(TARGET_CFLAGS)" LDFLAGS="$(TARGET_LDFLAGS)" $(MAKE) -C $(PACKAGE_SRCDIR)

Answer (score 0):

Libraries have been installed in:
xyz/buildroot/output/host/usr/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:

- add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
  during execution
- add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
  during linking
- use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
- have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.